# Simple way to create an image file with drawing commands in console program

Tags: c#, .net, drawing

I want to create a console program which, when run, creates an image file with some programmatically generated drawings. It will eventually read some configuration file with numeric parameters, then create the image algorithmically.

I can already get what I want with HTML5 Canvas and Javascript, using drawing commands like `fillRect()`, etc.

I have taken a look at the (excessively) vast .NET documentation about this, specially `System.Drawing` and `System.Windows.Media` namespaces, but there seems to be so many ways to use those classes that I don't even know where to start.

A pseudocode (not actual class names!!!) example of what I plan to do would be this:

```
RasterImage raster = new RasterImage(width, height);
context = raster.getContext();
context.fillColor = 'white';
context.DrawRectangle(x,y,w,h);
context.saveAsPng('result.png');
```

I believe an actual solution would be much more verbose than this, but that is the current workflow I need to perform. Also, it would be interesting if this class could not depend too much on WPF (it's a console program), but actually use more generic drawing classes if possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070365/how-to-generate-an-image-from-text-on-fly-at-runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` class and it's entourage, you could do it very simply like:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

    int width = 512;
    int height = 512;

    int x, y, w, h;
    x = y = 10;
    w = h = 100;

    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height)) {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {

            g.FillRectangle(
                brush: new SolidBrush(
                    color: Color.Blue
                ),
                rect: new Rectangle(x, y, w, h)
            );

            g.DrawRectangle(
                pen: new Pen(
                    color: Color.Black, 
                    width: 3
                ),
                rect: new Rectangle(x, y, w, h)
            );

            bmp.Save(@"D:\result.png", ImageFormat.Png);

        }
    }

}
```

You will need to reference the `System.Drawing` assembly and also add the
following `using` clauses:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```