# create image from text(email) to prevent spammers use

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net website and want to show users information in some pages. One of their infos is their email. I want to create an image from email and show it instead of text so that the spammers can not obtain it... how can I create image from text? or is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this answer, it should help guide you in the right direction. It draws text on an image.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2070493/907388

This article also is a great example to generate an image from text or convert text into image

http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/05/09/generate-image-from-text-using-c-or-convert-text-in-to-image-using-c/

You can also generate images from text server side with [imageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

EDIT:

The methods above assume you will save the image. The following method below will encode the image object to `Base64` string so you do not have to save the image directly.

```
public string ImageToBase64(Image image,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format) 
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
  {
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64String;
  }
}
```

After encoding the image, use the `base64String` return value from `ImageToBase64` in an `img` as such:

`<img src="data:image/png;base64, iAAANSUhEQAA..." alt="my encoded image"/>`

Just replace `iAAANSUhEQAA...` with the actual value, which could be quite large depending on the size of the image.

And one more note, data-uri do not work in IE6/7

credit: http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx

Comment: 2 first links shows how to create image in c#.net ... I should save them and then use them in asp.net , Am I right? Is there any way to use them without saving them? or how can I remove them after closing the window? By using image magic I should save them too, yes?

Comment: Yes, you are right. you should save them and use them in asp.net. The alternative to saving them is to encode the images to `Base64` and use that as the `<img src=""/>`. See my answer edit above on how to do this. Hope this helps