# Unix Banner Library for C#

Tags: c#, dll

Back in the late eighties I seem to remember using a unix utility method named 'banner' - (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_(Unix)  It basically took a string of text and 'rendered' it as a larger text 'banner' using each character as blocks to form the original character.  It was usually used at the start of print runs to create a heading for multi-sheet reports.

Does anyone know of a C# library that reproduces this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I remember a similar thing on the VAX mainframes at college. useful with a roomful of people banging in Pascal programs on VT100 terminals, and only one matrix printer behind closed doors in the hallowed office where the IT staff worked.

Anyway, this is a [C# ASCII art creator](https://code.google.com/p/asciiartcreator/) - if you could find a way of [rendering your text to a graphic file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070365/how-to-generate-an-image-from-text-on-fly-at-runtime) you could then convert it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could invoke a free software C program doing the same, perhaps [figlet](http://www.figlet.org/)