# imageresizer plugin text to image

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I need to convert text into an image.  Does anyone know if I can use the *creative version* of [imageresizer.net](http://imageresizer.net) to do this?

I have searched a lot but haven't found anything to confirm or deny imageresizer can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Why use [imagerezier](/questions/tagged/imagerezier) when you can do it with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) out-of-box?  From https://stackoverflow.com/a/2070493/1224069:

```
 private Image DrawText(String text, Font font, Color textColor, Color backColor)
 {
    //first, create a dummy bitmap just to get a graphics object
    Image img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //measure the string to see how big the image needs to be
    SizeF textSize = drawing.MeasureString(text, font);

    //free up the dummy image and old graphics object
    img.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();

    //create a new image of the right size
    img = new Bitmap((int) textSize.Width, (int)textSize.Height);

    drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //paint the background
    drawing.Clear(backColor);

    //create a brush for the text
    Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

    drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, 0, 0);

    drawing.Save();

    textBrush.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();

    return img;
}
```

Comment: I can do it from c# code, but as i am using purchased version of image resizer plugin, so just a concern, is this supports or not?

Comment: I am going to posit that it does not, but your best bet might be to contact their support: support@imageresizing.net

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, i did that waiting for their response, was in hurry so posted here. :)