# SQL Server reporting service word format rendering read only text box

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ms-word, openxml, ssrs-2012

I have created a SSRS report, which contains one text box field with generated date and time (look like a watermark). This report will rendered as Word format. The issue is some users rendered that report as Word document, then edit that generated date time and send that to clients.

Is there any way to prevent a text box to be read only or unchangeable after rendered as Word using ssrs? In general MS Word we can apply restriction in some part of the document (using review pane). My intention to achieve that using SSRS or SSRS with c# code.

At the moment we are not using PDF rendering because users have to type some text into the document.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no option to prevent  something from editing when it is being generated to Word document.

**But you can use this as workaround**

This is the direction I would go with:

1. Generate an image having the date and time within it.

You can use this part by using c# - [Please review this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070365/how-to-generate-an-image-from-text-on-fly-at-runtime)

Or you can even try generating the image on the fly within the SSRS by adding the drawing assembly - [Look at this post](https://blog.oraylis.de/2012/04/ssrs-custom-drawing/)

2. Second you need to convert the image to binary code (you don't really have to)
3. Just place the image wherever you want in the report.

users can't modify images in word :)

Hope this direction helps