# Converting Scanned PDF's to an Image

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, tesseract

I'm able to scan a JPG image using Tesseract, I'm able to scan a regular PDF using ITextSharp and get the text from those.  But I can't find a way to either get the text from a scanned PDF with a .PDF extension, or convert a PDF to an image so I can then scan it with Tesseract.  Are there any options that I'm missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have scanned the PDF document. Secondly assuming you have only text in the PDF document. You can generate an image from text from the following method

```
private Image DrawText(String text, Font font, Color textColor, Color backColor)
{
    //first, create a dummy bitmap just to get a graphics object
    Image img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //measure the string to see how big the image needs to be
    SizeF textSize = drawing.MeasureString(text, font);

    //free up the dummy image and old graphics object
    img.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();

    //create a new image of the right size
    img = new Bitmap((int) textSize.Width, (int)textSize.Height);

    drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //paint the background
    drawing.Clear(backColor);

    //create a brush for the text
    Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

    drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, 0, 0);

    drawing.Save();

    textBrush.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();

    return img;

}
```

Reference: [How to generate an image from text on fly at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070365/how-to-generate-an-image-from-text-on-fly-at-runtime)