# Display website JS source code on HTML background with only front-end code

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I display the current front-end JS source code (1 file) on the HTML as some sort of background? I am currently displaying a static image of my code as the background, but this must be updated manually each time the code changes, which isn't good. The JS source code is pretty short - around 50 lines.

EDIT: 
Also, I don't need the code to be actually an image. For example, it could just be text on a div. But if I'm just displaying the text, it must not mess up the flow of the document (I need to be able to display other elements on top).

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Can you give an example?

Comment: Do you have access to server side programming or can this be a build time task? i.e. could you run a file when you build your site?

Comment: @Mauro no, I just have front-end html/css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can request local resource using `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()`, use `<canvas>` to set words of script to `canvas`, call `.toDataURL()` on `canvas`, set resulting `data URL` as `background` of specific element.

Answer (score 2):

There might be an unexpected way to show your scripts via display:

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jwRgNO

```js
// some text to display from a script tag
```

```css
head, script {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script>// some text to display from a script tag within the <body> tag</script>
<p> here goes some regular content</p>
```

then, position can be used to take it off the flow of the document

If the js is linked, see comments below

Comment: how can this work if the script tag links to a js file?

Comment: @frozen it cannot work in that case, you might give a try to the iframe or object tag  ... https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/QgRbLp again something unexpected :) Best is anyway to use a library on server side to produce a jpeg file . PhP would do that and it would also be able to update the image produce every time that the timestamp of js file is updated ..

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to server side code execution you could use a process similar to this [How to generate an image from text on fly at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070365/how-to-generate-an-image-from-text-on-fly-at-runtime) which lets you generate an image from text

```
private Image DrawText(String text, Font font, Color textColor, Color backColor)
{
    //first, create a dummy bitmap just to get a graphics object
    Image img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //measure the string to see how big the image needs to be
    SizeF textSize = drawing.MeasureString(text, font);

    //free up the dummy image and old graphics object
    img.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();

    //create a new image of the right size
    img = new Bitmap((int) textSize.Width, (int)textSize.Height);

    drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //paint the background
    drawing.Clear(backColor);

    //create a brush for the text
    Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

    drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, 0, 0);

    drawing.Save();

    textBrush.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();

    return img;

}
```

Alternatively if you can't execute code server side you could maybe use ImageMagick as described here (http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=15869)

```
convert -size 250x250 -fill black -font Helvetica caption:@text.txt text.gif
```

Where text.txt is your source file and text.gif is the output file.  The rest is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need an actual image, you can fetch your code and wrap it in `<pre><code></code></pre>`. Then set it to a lower z-index than your main content.

```
<pre style="position:absolute; z-index:1; pointer-events:none;"><code></code></pre>
<div style="position:relative; z-index:2;"></div>
<script>
  fetch('/yourscript.js').then(response=>response.text()).then(text=>{
     document.querySelector('code').innerText = text;
  });
<script>
```

You would need to stylize it as needed, eg setting width/height, font-size

---

If you want to be able to use it as an actual background, then you would need to use `<svg>` with the use of `<foreignObject>`. After which you can use to create object urls.

1. Fetch your code
2. Build the correct svg XML, inserting your code into the correct place, eg inside a `<pre>` tag within `<foreignObject>`.
3. Then using that xml create a blob with mime type `image/svg+xml`
4. Finally create an object url from that blob. The url then can be used in place of an actual image url.

---

```
fetch('/yourscript.js').then(response=>response.text()).then(text=>{
   var data = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="800" height="500">
                 <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
                    <pre xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                      <code>${text}</code>
                    </pre>
                 </foreignObject>
           </svg>`;
   var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
   var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(svg);
   document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${url})`;
});
```

Note the width/height attributes of the `<svg>`, anything drawn outside of those dimensions will not be seen, so use the appropriate values for your targets.

---

And if you wanted an actual image file you could just then use that object url as the src for an `Image`, draw it on a `<canvas>` and call `toDataURL`

For the actual text highlighting (like that in your example image) you would need to do extra work, like wrapping the correct text in styled elements before using it.