# How To Save Image Bitmap in.ashx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, save-image

*My Code:*

```
<asp:Image ID="myImage" ImageUrl="~/GetImage.ashx?id=Chiken" runat="server" />
```

## Code Behind:

```
public Image DrawText(String text, Font font, Color textColor, Color backColor)
{
    //first, create a dummy bitmap just to get a graphics object
    Image img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);
    //measure the string to see how big the image needs to be
    SizeF textSize = drawing.MeasureString(text, font);
    //free up the dummy image and old graphics object
    img.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();
    //create a new image of the right size
    img = new Bitmap((int)textSize.Width, 80);

    drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    //paint the background
    drawing.Clear(backColor);

    //create a brush for the text
    Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

    drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, 0, 0);

    drawing.Save();

    textBrush.Dispose();
    drawing.Dispose();

    return img;
}
```

And Call Back in ashx file

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Font font = new Font("Revalo Modern Regular", 44, FontStyle.Bold);
        Color color = Color.FromArgb(242, 139, 0);
        Color background = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
        Image img = DrawText(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"].ToString(), font, color, background);
        img.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

### Tried:

```
img.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../Images/"+context.Response.OutputStream.ToString()))
```

I', tried [How to generate an image from text on fly at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070365/how-to-generate-an-image-from-text-on-fly-at-runtime)

### Photo after bitmap creation

[Photo after bitmap creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGeuc.png)

Comment: What is going wrong? Did you unit test `DrawText()` independent of the web service?

Comment: Photo after bitmap creation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGeuc.png

Comment: Do you get any errors? Please specify. What does happen, what doesn't?

Comment: I do not know how to save images with the Image object. I just saved it by saving the regular file by getting MapPath and SaveAs.
I'm looking for an answer.
If you know, help me! Please...

Comment: File Name IMG When I ViewSource: https://imgur.com/a/hBFnJJF

Comment: @Bất what's wrong with saving the file like you are doing in the SaveAs method?