# Use an Icon Font in Xamarin Forms TabBar

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am just getting started with Xamarin Forms, so please excuse what may well be a rookie question...

I started out with a new Shell Forms App in Visual Studio, so some code was generated for me.

There is an AppShell page which contains a TabBar control. Inside this are Tab controls were I can set my ShellContent pages.

Each Tab has an Icon property, but this apparently only accepts PNG icons.

How can I use an icon font (which is already hooked up to display icons correctly as I am using them in the content of another page) for my Tab icons in Xaml?

I am using Xamarin.Forms 4.0.0.497661

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to use FontImageSource to do that.

`<Tab Title="MyTitle">
    <Tab.Icon>
       <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource IconFont}" Glyph="&#xF00A;" Size="Small"/>
    </Tab.Icon>
 ...
</Tab>`

Comment: Brilliant, this worked, thanks. The only issue seems to be with the `Size` property - I can only get this to work with a number rather than a string.

Answer (score 3):

The solution below worked for me.

Copied the files from fontawesome inside Assets folder

- fa-brands-400.ttf
- fa-regular-400.ttf
- fa-solid-900.ttf

Important the reference "Font Awesome 5 Brands" according to icon needed

```
<Tab.Icon>
    <FontImageSource FontFamily="fa-brands-400.ttf#Font Awesome 5 Brands" Glyph="&#xf39e;"/>
</Tab.Icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a great question. You can't use the tab icon property in a straight forward way to accept the icon font, unless you convert it into a PNG. 
If you want to go that route, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070365/how-to-generate-an-image-from-text-on-fly-at-runtime), you might have to deal with permissions for saving images. Worth a try!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with custom renderers as a workaround. Check this example on GitHub here: https://github.com/winstongubantes/Xamarin.Forms/tree/master/CustomIconizeFont